# Python3 - Number of islands - LeetCode question

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

I am trying to solve this leetcode question:
https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/

```
    visited: List[List[int]] = None
    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        self.visited = [[0] * len(grid[0])] * len(grid)
        m, n = 0, 0
        islands = 0
        while m < len(grid):
            while n < len(grid[0]):
                print(m,n)
                islands = self.recur(grid,m,n,islands)
                n = n + 1
            m = m +1
        return islands
        
    def recur(self, grid: List[List[str]],m: int, n: int, islands: int) -> int:
        print(m,n,grid[m][n])
        if grid[m][n] == "1" and self.visited[m][n] == 0:
            down, right = None, None
            if m < len(grid) - 1:
                down = self.recur(grid,m+1, n, islands)
            if n < len(grid[0]) - 1:
                right = self.recur(grid,m, n+1, islands)
            
            if right is not None and down is not None:
                islands = min(islands,down,right) + 1
            elif right is not None:
                islands = min(islands,right) + 1
            elif down is not None:
                islands = min(islands,down) + 1
            else:
                islands = islands + 1
        self.visited[m][n] = 1
        print(self.visited)
        return islands
```

My idea is to use recursion and if 1 is encountered keep going downwards and then towards right until a zero is encountered. I wanted to use a `visited` variable to keep track of all the already visited values in `grid` and skip recursion for those.

But I noticed that wrong cells are getting updated in `visited`:

for the first iteration, m =0 and n =0, here is the output:

```
0 0
0 0 1
1 0 1
2 0 1
3 0 0
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
2 1 1
3 1 0
[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
2 2 0
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
1 1 1
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
0 1 1
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

All the 3 digits lines indicate the `m`,`n` and `grid[m][n]` values each time the `recur` method is called. I am printing the `visited` at the end of the method. I notice that the `m`,`n` values that were not visited were also getting updated to `1` in `visited`.

I am not able to figure out why this is happening and it's giving me a wrong result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think `self.visited = [[0] * len(grid[0])] * len(grid)` is going to give you issues. Initializing a 2D array like this causes references to the same mutable object (in this case `[0]`) within your list items. In other words, modifying visited[0][0] changes all elements in visited[0].

Comment: Thank you. That seemed to have resolved the issue. please post it as an answer and i'll accept it. @h0r53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.visited = [[0] * len(grid[0])] * len(grid)` is going to give you issues. Initializing a 2D array like this causes references to the same mutable object (in this case `[0]`) within your list items. In other words, modifying `visited[0][0]` changes all elements in `visited[0]`.

Try something like this:

`visited = [['0'] * len(grid[0]) for _ in range(len(grid))]`